# Don't show column in a table when value is 0

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table with three ligne and three column in a php page, I want to know how to not show a ligne when the value of data sent from the database is 0?

[image: here is the table]

I have always data sent from the database to the 2 lignes in blue but for the red one there is not always data sent to this ligne, so I want to know how to hide this ligne when there is not a data sent from the database.
The code that I have actually:

```
<table class="table-striped" id="">
  <tr>
    <th>Title 1</th>
    <th>Title 2</th>
    <th>Title 3</th>
    <th>Title 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $td1; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $td2; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <?php echo $td3; ?>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <?php echo $td4; ?>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $td5; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $td6; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <?php echo $td7; ?>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <?php echo $td8; ?>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- the ligne bellow that i want to no show if the data sent is 0   -->
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php echo $td9; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $td10; ?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <?php echo $td11; ?>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <?php echo $td12; ?>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: jeoren thanks for ther link but i don't see how can it help me in my query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have nothing in `$td9` or `$td10` or ... it means there is no 3rd row in database result, so put the `if` before 3rd data row!

```
  <table class="table-striped" id="">
     <tr>
     <th>Title 1</th>
     <th>Title 2</th>
     <th>Title 3</th>
     <th>Title 4</th>
     </tr> 
     <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo $td1; ?></td>
     <td> <?php echo $td2; ?></td>
     <td>
     <ul>
      <?php echo $td3; ?>
     </ul>
     </td>
     <td>
     <ul>
      <?php echo $td4; ?> 
     </ul>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo $td5; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $td6; ?></td>
     <td>
     <ul><?php echo $td7; ?> </ul>
     </td>
     <td>
     <ul><?php echo $td8; ?></ul>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <!-- the ligne bellow that i want to no show if the data sent is 0   --> 
  <?php if($td9){ ?>
     <tr>
     <td><?php echo $td9; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $td10; ?></td>
     <td>
     <ul><?php echo $td11; ?></ul>
     </td>
     <td>
     <ul><?php echo $td12; ?></ul>
     </td>
     </tr>
  <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much MohaMad this is what i was looking for exactly !